# PHP imagealphablending alternative for svg

Tags: php, svg, gd, masking, alphablending

Following is a task I have done using PHP GD. And I want to do similar thing in SVG.

```
//Part One
$img = @imagecreatetruecolor(80, 80);
$red = imagecolorallocatealpha($img,255,0,0,0);
$green = imagecolorallocatealpha($img,0,255,0,60);

imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, 80, 80, $red);    
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagefilledrectangle($img, 10, 10, 70, 70, $green);


//Part Two
$img2 = @imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$blue = imagecolorallocatealpha($img2,0,0,255,0);
imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, 100, 100, $blue);

//Part Three
imagecopy($img2, $img, 10, 10, 0, 0, 80, 80);

//Part Four
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($img2);
```

Description:

1. Part 1 (Creating First Image):-

a: Creates a 80px / 80px image,

b: Filled by Red Color,

c: Image's alphablending is made off.

d: Image's middle is filled with Green Color with Opacity.

2. Part 2 (Creating Second Image):-

a. Creates a 100px / 100px image

b. image filled by blue color

3. Part 3 (Copying Image):- First image is overlayed into second image in the center
4. Part 4 (Display Image):- Displays the final image

[Click here to see the image created by this code](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10731157_10205050834608209_5184024845049313508_n.jpg?oh=4ccb928fa0dac9f6619b0cbcf7fba631&oe=54B85C7B&__gda__=1422067053_ba90fe187aa72cea849e05ff47450b66)

The green part of first image is blended with the second image. But, Red part of first image didn't.

I want to exactly the same thing in SVG. How can I do that? How can I make an image object's alpahblending off, so the image behind this can be blended with the image over that image?

**Update:**
Found something interesting to solve this problem. Tried the following SVG code:

```
<html><body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"> 
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" /> 
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>

        <mask id="mask3" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" >
            <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="100" ry="100" fill="url(#grad3)" />
        </mask>
    </defs>     
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff;"/>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000; "/>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="60" height="60" style="stroke: none; fill: #00ff00; mask: url(#mask3)"/>
</svg>
</body></html>
```

Third rectangle should display a color that is provided in the "Mask", now it is showing the gradient defined in mask but I have to provide the fill color. I want to show the exactly same color or gradient I have defined in mask. How can I do that?

Comment: You question is not very clear and I suggest you edit it to explain clearly what you are trying to achieve. What are you asking: can someone provide code to do the above, but output as SVG? Or, how to merge images with transparency in the code you posted?

Comment: I need SVG alternative of the code I have posted. How to do the same thing in SVG. As I have got something in my studies, that I can use mask for doing this. I tried with something like this:

<svg>
</svg>

Comment: <svg width="100" height="100"><defs><linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"> <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" /> <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" /></linearGradient><mask id="mask3" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" ><ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="100" ry="100" fill="url(#grad3)" /></mask></defs>  
<rect x="1" y="1" width="80" height="100" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff; mask: url(#mask3)"/><rect x="100" y="1" width="80" height="100" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff; mask: url(#mask3)"/></svg>